# DiffBuilder - ignore element value but make sure the XML node is present

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xmlunit

I am using `DiffBuilder` to compare two XML files.
For the given element Product, I want to check that the element is present but I want to ignore its value.
Is it possible using [XmlUnit](https://www.xmlunit.org/) ?

My code below will work regardless of the presence of the Product element, which doesn't work for what I need

```
var differenceBuilder = DiffBuilder
                .Compare(Input.FromDocument(controlXmlFile))
                .WithTest(Input.FromDocument(testXmlDile))
                .WithNodeFilter(n => n.Name != "Product");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you don't want to throw away the node itself but the differences between the nodes. You wouldn't use a `NodeFilter` but rather a `DifferenceEvaluator` for this.

A very simplified version could be something like

```
.WithDifferenceEvaluator((comparison, outcome) =>
        comparison.ControlDetails.Target.Name == "Product" ? ComparisonResult.EQUAL : outcome
    )
```

but you'd need to take into account that `ControlDetails` could be `null` (and look at `TestDetails` instead) for example. And if your `Product` node has child elements you may want to either filter them out with `NodeFilter` or check whether any parent of the current comparison target is named `Product`.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using my own `DifferenceEvaluator` but your solution works.